# LINQ Join doesn't recognize symbol

Tags: c#, linq

Can someone please tell me why this simple join will not compile? It doesn't recognize the property "Name" or the anonymous types m and l. The error messages are:

> Error 1   The name 'm' is not in scope on the left side of 'equals'. 
>   Consider swapping the expressions on either side of 'equals'.
>
> Error 2   The name 'l' is not in scope on the right side of 'equals'. 
>   Consider swapping the expressions on either side of 'equals'.

```
var l1 = new List<L1>();
var m2 = new List<M2>();

var rs = from l in l1
         join m in m2 on m.Name equals l.Name
         select new {l1};

public class L1
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class M2
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `join m in m` should have been `join m in m2`. Second, in LINQ order of operands in `equals` matters, so it should be `l.Name equals m.Name`.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to SQL, LINQ is sensetive about the order of the operands in the comparison expression. Swap the `m.Name` and `l.Name` around the `equals` operator:

```
join m in m2 on l.Name equals m.Name
```